# Textbox with duration step counter in HHHH:MM:DD format

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textbox, duration

This question is about seeking advise. I need a textbox which can accept or set HHHH:MM:SS duration (not 12 or 24 hour time)

Example: 23518 hours: 59 minutes : 01 seconds
**23518:59:01**
I need to use a step counter to increase or decrease the value based on the current cursor.

I have searched the plugins, but none found for this use case.

Any pointer are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to roll your own. The html5 time spinner only allows 23 as max hours

Comment: If there is no code or effort, it is often closed as off topic: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to roll your own - like this

```js
const pad = (num) => ("0"+num).slice(-2)
document.querySelectorAll(".pad").forEach(
  ele => ele.addEventListener("change",e => 
    e.target.value = pad(e.target.value)
  )  
)
document.getElementById("hours").addEventListener("change",e => {
  let tgt = e.target;
  let val = tgt.value;
  if (val.length<3) {
    val=pad(val)
    tgt.value=val;
  }  
})
```

```css
input[type=number] {
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<input id="hours" type="number" min="0" max="99999" value="00"/>:<input id="min" class="pad" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="01" max="59" value="00" />:<input id="sec" class="pad" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="01" max="59" value="00" />
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you help me pad for HH as well? 2 should be 02, 344 should be 344, 1 should be 01